# f(n) = Sigma of I*Log(I) , where I=1 to Log(n) , equals what?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm trying to calculate the following :

```
f(n) = ∑ (i*log(i))  , when i=1 to log(n) .
```

How do I do that ?

I have succeeded doing :

```
f(n) = ∑ (i*log(i))  , when i=1 to n .
```

Which is : `1*log(1) + 2*log(2) + ... + n*log(n) <= n(n*log(n))`

Where in the end : `f(n) = ∑ (i*log(i)) = Ω(n^2  log^2(n) )` (`Where i=1 to n`)

But I don't know how to do the first one , any idea anybody ?

Regards

Comment: Couldn't you just substitute the 'n' in the 2nd function as 'log n'?

Comment: Please write you formula in tex style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to remove `^2` from `log^2(n)` in your current result would be

```
f(n) = ∑ (i*log(i)) <= n(n*log(n)) = Ω(n^2*log(n))
```

Then, for the case where `i` goes from `1` to `log(n)`, just substitute `n` by `log(n)`.

Let's define

```
g(n) = ∑ (i*log(i)), when i=1 to log(n) // The result you are looking for
f(n) = ∑ (i*log(i)), when i=1 to n // The result we have
```

Then

```
g(n) = f(log(n)) = Ω(log(n)^2*log(log(n)))
```

Comment: First , thanks . Second , I'm looking for this : ∑ (i*log(i)), when i=1 to log(n) .... and not that : ∑ (i*log(i)), when i=1 to n .... :)

Comment: Yes, that's the function `g` in my answer.

Comment: Okay , but why did you say that I have to remove ^2 from log^2(n) ?

Comment: Because it is incorrect: `n(n*log(n)) = n*n*log(n) = n^2*log(n)` and not `n^2 log^2(n)`.

Comment: In the final answer , log(n)^2 is the same as log^2(n)) ? Looks like (log(n))^2 , or am I wrong  ? or did you mean log(n^2) ?

Comment: As I said, I noted `log(log(n))` as `log^2(n)` using the [functional powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Functional_powers) notation. But you can keep the form `Ω(log(n)^2*log(log(n)))` if you like it better.

Comment: @sch Shouldn't it be Big O instead of Big Omega for first requirement? 

f(n) = ∑ (i*log(i))  , when i=1 to n 
O(n^2*log(n))

Answer (score 1):

f(n) = Theta(log<sup>2</sup>(n) * log(log(n))

Proof:

```
f(n) = 1 * log(1) + 2 * log(2) + ... + log(n) * log(log(n)) <= 
<= log(n)*log(log(n)) * log(n) =
= O(log^2(n) * loglog(n))

f(n) = 1 * log(1) + 2 * log(2) + ... + log(n) * log(log(n)) >= 
>= log(n/2) * log(log(n/2)) + log(n/2 + 1) * log(log(n/2 + 1) + ... + log(n) * log(log(n)) >= 
>= log(n/2) * log(log(n/2)) + ... + log(n/2) * log(log(n/2)) = 
= log(n/2) * log(log(n/2)) * log(n/2)
= log^2(n/2)*log(log(n/2)) = log^2(n/2)*log(log(n)-log(2)) = 
= Omega(log^2(n)*loglog(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know some calculus, you can often find the order of growth of such sums by integration.

If `f` is a positive monotonic function, `∑ f(i)` for `1 <= i <= k` can be approximated by the integral `∫ f(t) dt` (`t` ranging from 1 to `k`). So if you know a primitive function `F` of `f` (in modern parlance an *antiderivative*), you can easily evaluate the integral to `F(k) - F(1)`. For growth analysis, the constant term `F(1)` is irrelevant, so you can approximate the sum (as well as the integral) simply by `F(k)`.

A tool that is often useful in such calculations is *partial integration*,

```
b                                         b
∫ f'(t)*g(t) dt = f(b)*g(b) - f(a)*g(a) - ∫ f(t)*g'(t) dt
a                                         a
```

which follows from the *product rule* `(f*g)' = f' * g + f * g'`. It is often helpful to write `f` as `1*f` in order to apply partial integration, for example to find a primitive of the (natural) logarithm,

```
∫ log t dt = ∫ 1*log t dt = t*log t - ∫ t * (log t)' dt = t*log t - ∫ t*(1/t) dt = t*log t - t
```

In this case, with `f(t) = t*log t`, partial integration yields

```
∫ t*log t dt = 1/2*t^2 * log t - ∫ (1/2*t^2) * (log t)' dt
             = 1/2*t^2 * log t - 1/2 ∫ t^2*(1/t) dt 
             = 1/2*t^2 * log t - 1/4*t^2
```

Since the second term grows slower than the first, it can be ignored for growth analysis, so you obtain

```
k
∑ i*log i ≈ 1/2*k^2*log k
1
```

Since logarithms to different bases only differ by a constant factor, a different choice of logarithm just changes the constant factor, and you see that in all cases

```
k
∑ i*log i ∈ Θ(k^2 * log k)
1
```

For your specific problem, `k = log n`, so the sum is `Θ((log n)^2 * log(log n))`, as has been derived in a different way by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/7012/5f1ff74e3e6e4a72bbd5483.png
now subtitute n for logn and you'll get it's VERY tightly bounded by log^2(n)*log(log(n))